# How can I prepopulate the 'name' in the TextInput on iOS without it showing as a suggestion using autoComplete or textContentType?

Tags: xcode, react-native, autocomplete

I'm working on an iOS app and facing an issue with a TextInput field. I want to prepopulate the 'name' field in the TextInput component, but I'm encountering a problem where it shows as a suggestion, which I'd like to avoid.

I've tried using autoComplete and textContentType attributes, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. What's the right way to achieve prepopulation of the 'name' field without it being suggested?

Here is the explanation:

```
 <TextInput
    textContentType="name"
    autoFocus={true}
  />
```

In this above code the name shows in as keyboard suggestion. How can i prepopulate it on the input field without click it on the suggestion?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIrYT.png)

Comment: Hi,  l welcome to SO. Please show enough code so others can understand and reproduce the problem. Take a look at [ask] when you can.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.